# ionic/Angularjs - not able to unchecked check box on ng-change

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have one drop down and a check box, i want to **reset check box value to false** **whenever drop-down value change**. I had already written code for reset check box value to false, but it is not working, please tell me where i am doing wrong.

**View:**

```
<label class="item item-input item-select">
        <div class="input-label">Leave Type</div>
        <select ng-model="LeaveRequest.leaveType" ng-change="leavetypechange(LeaveTypes)" required>
          <option value="">Select Leave Type</option>
          <option ng-repeat="lt in LeaveTypes"value="{{lt.Name}} ">{{lt.Name}}</option>
       </select>
</label>
<div ng-show="ShowPeriod">
      <ion-checkbox  ng-model="isChecked" >Half day/ Quarter leave</ion-checkbox>
</div>
```

**controller:**

```
.controller('ApplyLeaveCtrl',function($scope, $state, $templateCache,$ionicPopup) {
 $scope.leavetypechange=function(){ 
            $scope.isChecked=false;
            };
});
```

Comment: Can you provide the codepen? It will be helpful for debug your code.

Comment: Plz update LeaveTypes on your controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$scope.isChecked in loop is creating seperate scope for each item in dropdown.

so you need to put it in service.

```
.service('dataService', function() {
    this.isChecked;
})
```

here is  you working codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwzLqO

Comment: Its throwing me error when i build my code, "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression. this.IsChecked" in service

Comment: show by default allocate false.  this.isChecked=false; in dataService

Answer (score 0):

Use $parent with isChecked as follow:

```
<ion-checkbox  ng-model="$parent.isChecked" >Half day/ Quarter leave</ion-checkbox>
```